# Updates in ListView are not saved after restarting the application

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, onresume

My application consists of 2 activities .
The first one which contains a list from where i send rows one by one to the second activity :http://postimg.org/image/5pmlso0ct/
The second activity (i added some rows ) : http://postimg.org/image/sr9zvqp2d/

My problem appears when i close the application and start it again , on the second activity i'm getting only the last row I 've sent from the first activity :
http://postimg.org/image/7tuu2ptdl/
I also tried to create another class to save the arraylist which populates the listview ,but it doesn't seem to work I guess

~First Activity~

```
 @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                               int position, long arg3) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("Save",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    textView4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    textView5 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
    n =textView4.getText().toString();
    m=textView5.getText().toString();
    MyObject=new CustomObject(n,m);




    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(MyObject);
    editor.putString("MyObject", json);
    editor.apply();
```

~Second Activity~

```
   public class Favorites extends Activity{
   private ListView lv;
  private String n, m;
  private CustomObject obj;
  private SaveData save;
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

List<CustomObject> favorites=new ArrayList<>();



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.forthlistview);



    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Save",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


}


private void fillFavoriteList() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedpreferences.getString("MyObject", "");
    obj = gson.fromJson(json, CustomObject.class);
    favorites.add(obj);
    HashSet<CustomObject> hs = new HashSet<CustomObject>();
    hs.addAll(favorites);
    favorites.clear();
    favorites.addAll(hs);
    save.setGlobalArrayOfCustomObjects(favorites);

            adapter = new AdapterFavorites(Favorites.this, favorites);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}




protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  if(favorites==null)
  {favorites=save.getGlobalArrayOfCustomObjects(); fillFavoriteList();}
else fillFavoriteList();

    }

 }
```

~SaveData class~

```
   public class SaveData extends Favorites {



      private List<CustomObject> globalArray;

       public void setGlobalArrayOfCustomObjects(List<CustomObject> newArray){
       globalArray = newArray;
   }

    public List<CustomObject> getGlobalArrayOfCustomObjects(){
    return globalArray;
   }

 }
```